# python beautiful soup meta content tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the price from a web site that includes the following HTML:

```
<div class="book-block-price " itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope>
<meta itemprop="price" content="29.99"/>
<meta itemprop="price" content=""/>
    $ 29.99         </div>
```

I'm using the following Beautiful Soup code:

```
book_prices = soup_packtpage.find_all(class_="book-block-price ")
print(book_prices)
for book_price in book_prices:
    printable_version_price = book_price.meta.string
    print(printable_version_price)
```

print(book_prices) yields:

```
[<div class="book-block-price " itemprop="offers" itemscope=""    itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<meta content="29.99" itemprop="price"/>
<meta content="" itemprop="price"/>
            $ 29.99
```

print(printable_version_price) yields "None".

How do I deal with meta tags?  Or do I have other problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `book_price.meta` would match the first `meta` tag inside the book price block. And this first `meta` tag text is "empty" - this is why you are getting an empty string printed:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="29.99"/>
```

Instead, get the `content` attribute value:

```
book_price.meta["content"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with `lxml`'s `etree` (pseudo-code, but should be enough to get you going):

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(x) # where x is a file-like object, or parseString if x is a string.
print doc.xpath('//meta[itemprop="price"]/text()')
```